# Lengthening in-flight evaporation time of water droplet in air

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, water, evaporation

How one can increase the in-flight evaporation time of sprayed water droplets in air without changing the thermodynamic conditions of the ambient air ( i.e. RH, T ). For instance mixing water with some chemical additives (non-toxic) that does not change the property of water so much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question is how to increase evaporation amount because the time is the droplet traveling time.

To increase evaporation amount without changing air condition, followings can be considered.

1. reduce droplet size: the evaporation rate is proportion to $\frac {1}{D^2}$, where D is droplet diameter.
2. increase droplet speed: this can increase convection heat transfer so to keep the droplets' temperature up. Otherwise evaporation can cool down the droplet and thus reduces its temperature.

   3. same as above, high speed can also displace vapor so to reduce partial pressure, which is also good for evaporation.
   4. if you want to add something to water to increase its evaporation rate.